# Oracle: Create View From a Table with little different data

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view

I have Table Book with the data is :

```
BookID   Name   Type
------  ------  -----
  1       A      null
  2       B      null
```

How can I creat a View name [BookList] from table View like this:

```
Name   Type
----   ----
 A     Thin
 B     Thick
```

Comment: the values in column TYPE from table are null?

Comment: @user3131274: What is the logic to populate the `TYPE` column in the view , I mean where is `THIN,THICK` came from

Answer (score 2):

create view BookList as

```
select name,

type = case when name = 'A' then 'thin'

            when name = 'B' then 'thick'
            end
from book
```